# What to do if there're two answers with the shortest code?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

On my Code Golf ["Converting a string to lower-case (without built-in to-lower functions!)"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12760/converting-a-string-to-lower-case-without-built-in-to-lower-functions), there're two answers with the same character count (10 characters), and they're both the answer with the lowest character count. On StackExchange sites, it's not possible to accept two (or more) answers, so how can I decide which answer I should accept?

Comment: Which two answers? I see only [one answer of 10 characters](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12776).

Comment: @manatwork: then what about the Perl answer?

Comment: You asked for processing input and producing output. The Perl code needs `-p` option to achieve that. We used to count `-p` as +1 in code-golf challenges.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks! Changed my accept vote.

Comment: The usual explanation is that otherwise C would win everything. In this case [Rozuur's solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12780) could be 1 character: http://pastebin.com/a4skCs9c

Comment: I thought about the same loophole for java4k once. Write a small interp and have everything in the webstart file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Speaking as a person who posts occasional code golf challenges (and not as a moderator), I tend to pick the earlier-posted answer in cases of a tie. [Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188/stack-overflow-code-golf/597372#comment2449021_597372) (In this case, Adam Davis was [a proponent of Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9758/13), so this wasn't something he could dispute. :-P)

Answer (score -3):

I think the ties should be broken by the number of upvotes.

Comment: I'm not one of the downvoters, but I imagine someone could get a few sock puppets and game the system.